# What's the equivalent scaffholding of this project in C (coming from C#)?

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, architecture

I'm interested in learning C, and one of the things I like to do when I'm first learning a language is to try a handful of [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) questions.

If I were doing this in C#, I would write an interface that all of my questions would implement, and I would include things like a `PrintSolution()` method and a `ProblemStatement` property. Then I would create a custom `class` in individual files for each question, using a naming convention like `Problem1.cs`... `Problem123.cs`, etc. Each of these objects would implement the `problem` interface. This allows me to start fresh with each question instead of writing potentially long methods called `SolveProblem1`, `SolveProblem2`, etc. in one file, and then choosing which one to call in `main`.

Finally, for testing or revisiting a problem, I would have a driver class with a `main` method, and then to quickly show the solution to any problem I had solved, I could call this (replacing the 1 with the number of the problem I wanted):

```
Problem1 testProblem = new Problem1(); 
testProblem.PrintSolution();
Console.Read();
```

I know C isn't an object-oriented language, but is there a similar way to architect a solution in Visual Studio such that I can keep all my code in one location and run the answer to a problem on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers to functions may help you to achieve the desirable code composition in a procedural world.

[Function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)